What kind of trees to plant and where

I am trying to decide what trees to plant and their location on my property. Looking for large shade trees + something that will help cut down on dust from the frequently traveled dirt road.
I've attached a photo that details how the house sits plus the available land for planting. I've tried researching everything possible to make this decision but I'm stuck. I also have neighbors to the west of me that I'd like to block.
Note: I am thinking Tulip Poplars, Prairie Elms, Southern Magnolias, Royal Empress or Rainbow Eucalyptus but happy for any and all suggestions.
Important info: Growing Zone 9, Southern California

Where is the road? For reducing dust on a dirt road, broadcast calcium chloride chips, or spray with a solution of calcium chloride and water, for some distance either side of your house.  The only thing that would appear to fit with blocking neighbors to the west and this lot/house layout would be a fence. Any trees there are too close to the house unless the unscaled drawing is of a house the size of a football field.

The dimensions of your lot would be extremely helpful.

Hi  Rohit, I'll have to look into the calcium chloride option, thank you for that. I do have a fence to the west and it is very close to the house, I wouldn't put anything between the side of the house and theirs but I do have a large open area in the front of the house. The lot is about a 1/4 acre, house about 1600 SF.

I see room for one Magnolia upfront where the compass is and one in back.
